# AAD group delta query does not return members@delta anymore?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a client application leveraging Microsoft Graph to get incremental changes for a certain AAD Group.

My BVT caught an issue and when I debugged, I found the Graph request does not return the `members@delta` collection any longer so the app did not receive any Group Membership changes.

**Request:**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$expand=members&$select=id,displayName,mailNickName,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,groupTypes,securityEnabled&$filter=id eq '9f63ad39-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'`

**Response:**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups(id,displayName,mailNickname,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,groupTypes,securityEnabled,members())",​
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$skiptoken=duo2tEVrL.............................-Ay-zlyuo2tEVrLOUh0PUTdXM",​
    "value": [​
        {​
            "displayName": "TestGroup-OneUser",​
            "mailNickname": "9a234b7e8ad-3",​
            "securityEnabled": true,​
            "id": "9f63ad39-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",​
            "members@delta": [​
                {​
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",​
                    "id": "18e2a00c-xxxx-xxxx-a9a9-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"​
                }​
            ]​
        }​
    ]​
}
```

Any idea what has changed?

Comment: I don't understand, it looks like you're getting the membership changes in that response.

Comment: That was the expected response when it used to work. The response I am getting right now does not have the "members@delta" block.  I only got the general properties.  It's like I did not specify $expand=members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `members` to $select, change the request like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=id,displayName,members&$filter=id eq '1068699c-044b-4846-b45a-4137e06a7ca2'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I will update the request and try. But according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups) the query parameter **$expand=members** should be used? Is this parameter still supported? Thanks!

Comment: @Joyce It seems that $expand=members isn't working now. You can include members in $select.